# Jasper reports: Custom sorting order

Tags: sorting, jasper-reports

I have a field which has a set of different possible values as strings.
When showing the report table i'd like to state the sorting order explicitly.

For example:
i have 3 possible values:

```
AAA, BBB and CCC
```

The order i want them to appear is

```
BBB
AAA
CCC
```

Alphabetically would not work for this case.
I cannot do the sort when retrieving the data since i have a json data-source which i do not control.

I'm also not using the iReport editor im just editing the xml.

Comment: You can get data and sort it with Java.

Comment: I don't have access to the code on the server. I can only edit the report xml file.